# Why doesn't notifee work in react native?

Tags: react-native

When I installed the @notifee/react-native and ran the command `npx react-native run-android` it gives this error message.

Error Image

[image: 1]

What is the issue?

I tried adding this to the android manifest file
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`

and installing Android API 33

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/notifee/issues/561#issuecomment-1285108642 may be a good start. 

You should change your sdkVersion
compileSdkVersion = 33 and targetSdkVersion = 33
Gradle upgrade is required as well.

Comment: How can upgrade the gradle?

Comment: Thaks youuuu! It's wooorks :)